# Connecting Kafdrop to secure MSK kafka brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have a secure MSK cluster running apache kafka 2.2.1. If I create an ec2 instance in a private subnet (amazon linux 2) and install java and kafka, I can do the following to communicate with kafka:

`cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts /tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks`

Then make a file like

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

and pass in that file in the `--command-config` argument to some kafka cli commands.

I am trying to run kafdrop in an ECS container now, and I need to pass in this file. [The documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop) says I can pass in a base64 encoded version for `KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE` and `KAFKA_PROPERTIES` (I guess I can omit `KAFKA_KEYSTORE`?). However, if I base64 encode the truststore, it is this gigantic string that I have to copy-paste into the ECS task definition. Is there a way around this? Is it possible to create my own docker image with the kafdrop image as a base and then just add in the truststore file?

Answer (score 0):

With that default config you required to communicate with MSK using SSL, but since you didn't generated any certs on MSK - when deploying Kafdrop you can omit second string and your properties file and truststore at all, just make your client to use TLS, so as a solely additional argument you need to pass
`-e KAFKA_PROPERTIES="$(cat kafka.properties | base64)"` where `kafka.properties` contains only `security.protocol=SSL`

Comment: can u add the full command here , is it possible ?